# Does it hurt SEO to have a language redirect before 404?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, 404

I have a Django website with activated translation middleware for several languages.

If a user tries to open

```
example.com/abc
```

this happens:

1. the middleware detects the user language (from cookie, from browser, then fallback) and redirect to i.e.

   ```
   example.com/en/abc
   ```
2. the middleware detects that this page does not exist and sends a 404

For these non-existing pages I have first a 301 and then a 404. Does this redirect hurt my SEO ranking?

Comment: *Does this redirect hurt my SEO ranking?* Rank is a page by page thing. If your 301 results in a 404, then there is nothing to rank. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Language redirects and dynamic language determination are bad for SEO in general.    For SEO, language should be chosen *solely* based on the URL.  You should not redirect based on browser language settings (`accept-language` header) or IP address geo location.   Cookie redirects are fine for users that have affirmatively stated their language preference.

Your English pages (like `example.com/en/abc`) should link directly to other English pages (like `example.com/en/def`).  You should never link to URLs that would require a redirect to get to the appropriate language.

There are several reasons for this:

- Search engine crawlers don't send cookies
- Search engine crawlers don't send `accept-language` headers
- Search engine crawlers crawl sites worldwide from centralized data centers that are often in the United States.
- Non-English speakers often download web browsers that default to English.  The `accept-language` header is often incorrectly set to `en-US` because it is the default.
- People may use a borrowed computer that doesn't match their language or home country.   For example when vacationing and using an internet cafe.
- IP geolocation is very inaccurate.  It is wrong up to 10% of the time.

It is fine for SEO to use browser language and geo IP to put a message near the top of the page.  Something like:

> You appear to be in the United States using and English language browser.   Click here to move to the English website.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers seem to have missed the specific question being asked here. Yes, language auto-redirection can be problematic for SEO for the valid points raised in Stephen's answer.

However, the OP simply appears to be asking whether a redirect to a 404 is bad. The language redirection is just a bit of background explaining why this redirection is occurring in the first place.

> For these **non-existing pages** I have first a 301 and then a 404. Does **this redirect** hurt my SEO ranking?

As, @closetnoc pointed out in comments, whether you serve a 404 immediately or redirect to a 404, there is still nothing to index. It's ultimately a 404 either way you look at it. So, whilst the redirect itself is perhaps a little extra work, it's not going to "hurt" your SEO ranking. (SEO doesn't really come into it.)

Answer (score 0):

It does not hurt in SEO, because there are many of situation when people link to your sources and forgot to mention `/` slash at the end of URL, www and https, so your server may already redirect them by default, like this

```
http://www.example.com/source redirect to www.example.com/source/

http://example.com/source/ redirect to https://example.com/source/

example.com/source/ will redirect to www.example.com/source/
```

While may be in future, your source file is deleted by you, so all user and cralwer/spider will first see 301 redirection then 404 error, so it is common in many situation, hence I said it does not hurt in SEO.

But as stephen said, don't link your article in this way, **example.com/abc** because Google may not reach to your proper page. So make sure your all **example.com/en/abc** link to **example.com/en/source** only.

**Use Google fetch and render tool to see how Google view your redirection.**